# /etc/rc.d what does rc stand for?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

Do anybody have idea about full form of rc.d at?

```
  /etc/rc.d
```

It contain scripts to  is used to control the starting, stopping and restarting of daemons. But what exactly meaning of **rc** here, do anyone have clue?

Comment: Yes Daniel I found answer, the above links gives the same description what I am looking for is, thanks mate.

Answer (score 6):

It's all based off of Bell Labs System V Unix which was somewhere around when init and run levels were introduced.

It stands for `runcom` or `run commands`. In the question of anything Unix, consult the [Jargon File](http://jargon-file.org/archive/). There's a deep history, canonical and recorded that came before Linux

> :rc file: /R·C fi:l/, n.
>
> [Unix:  from  runcom  files  on  the  {CTSS}  system 1962-63, via the
>      startup  script  /etc/rc] Script file containing startup instructions
>      for an application program (or an entire operating system), usually a
>      text  file  containing  commands  of  the  sort  that might have been
>      invoked  manually  once the system was running but are to be executed
>      automatically  each  time  the system starts up. See also {dot file},
>      {profile} (sense 1).

Answer (score 2):

> It is derived from "**run commands**".

From [Unix FAQ](http://fisica.ehu.es/ref/unixfaq.html)

rc (as in ".cshrc" or "/etc/rc") = "RunCom"
    "rc" derives from "runcom", from the MIT CTSS system, ca. 1965.

> 'There was a facility that would execute a bunch of commands stored in
>   a file; it was called "runcom" for "run commands", and the file began
>   to be called "a runcom." "rc" in Unix is a fossil from that usage.'

Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie, as told to Vicki Brown "rc" is also the name of the shell from the new Plan 9 operating system.

Answer (score 1):

rc.d contains runlevels, I vote for runlevel control or possibly runlevel config

I don't think it's related to bashrc

Comment: My main question is to know about **rc** stand for what? So I think rc stand for run commands, so that means .bashrc contains commands to execute when ever new bash terminal opens. isn't it?

Comment: that's reasonable too, but runlevels are controlled in rc.d, ie init 3 , init 5 etc., so that was my logic. It probably could be either. Run Level Control is referenced in documentation from linuxfromscratch and the original sysv

Comment: the /etc/rc.X have nothing to do with .bashrc at all - in fact the commands in /etc/rc.X don't even need to be written in BASH to work.

Comment: I clearly understood that there is no connection between rc.X and bashrc, but now i understand meaning of rc. rc means run commands, so just explained what could be .bashrc means.

Comment: @user3134198 - You pretty much nailed it `runcom` or `run commands` which Unix inherited from CTSS (Compatible Time-Sharing System) and since `.bashrc` is an `init` file for `bash`, you find `rc` tacked onto its hame and a dot to hide it. This is a common *nix convention.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it stood for Run Command, but the guys over at  [linuxquestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-does-rc-stand-for-31758/) have a couple positions on it.

So it's probably one of these:

`- run commands


- resource control


- run control


- runtime configuration`

Sorry I can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Several positions because it came about before their time. From Unix. And earlier as in CTSS. After all, Unix was a play on the predecessor that seeded Kernigan, Ritchie, et.al., --> Multics. Computer Language and wordplay are the source for many names in Unix that Linux inherited.